# Slider gets reload in Table View in Iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uislider

In my app, i add a slider in Table view i.e. each row contains a slider & It also works fine.

But when i scroll the table view the slider get reload i.e. each shows me starting position rather than slider value.

```
//My code is as follow for slider in table cell:

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        return cell;
    }


    UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
        theSlider.maximumValue=99;
        theSlider.minimumValue=0;
        [cell addSubview:theSlider];

return cell;
}
```

**How can i solve this??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 NSString *CellIdentifier=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; UISlider*  theSlider =  [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(174,12,120,23)] autorelease];
    theSlider.maximumValue=99;
    theSlider.minimumValue=0;
    [cell addSubview:theSlider];
}  return cell;
```

This way the slider gets created only when cell is nil i.e cell gets created. and use [tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) method to set the slider value like slider.value = yourvalue;

Comment: Thank s for reply! But my table view or it does not show any row with this code.

Comment: I found one little problem in your solution. I have a next Button in my view.When i try to tab on it, I want to reload(i.e. set slider values to the minimum). I try to reload table but i did not get the desire result. **Please help once again**

Answer (score 2):

You need to store values of slider view and set the values of sliderview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `slider.value = yourvalue;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called not just once, but every time that the tableView need to render that cell... So you have to be sure that only initialize `theSlider` the first time is called...

The best approach is to define a custom `UITableViewCell` and put there a property that would store `theSlider`, then, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, check if it is already initialized or not, see:

```
// If the slider is not yet initialized, then do it
if(cell.theSlider == nil)
{
    // Init...
}
```

Comment: can you post some more code because how to write `cell.theSlider` in the method?

Comment: You have to create a custom UITableViewCell first, set it in the storyboard, drag there the slider and link it as IBOutlet to your custom UITableViewCell, then... you'll have the cell.theSlider property.

Check this: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 1):

This is really from "`cellForRowAtIndexPath`" method . Every time when you are scrolling every cell is getting `nil` and reinitialise it. Better you can try with creating custom cell class(BY creating sub class of `UITableViewCell`) and also the defining slider in condition "if `(cell == nil)`".